# How to do Data Encryption In Hadoop?

Tags: security, hadoop, encryption

How can I apply AES encryption to hadoop? Is it possible? If not, help me encrypt the data file in hadoop

Comment: What are you trying to encrypt? The communication between workers? Or the content that the workers are processing? In what way do you see it as any different than encryption in any other context?

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of hadoop supports encryption. We can create encrypted zones and the data that we transfer to these zones will be encrypted automatically and the data retrieved from this zone will be decrypted automatically. This is also known as REST data encryption. The detailed steps are given in the [apache website](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html). This doesn't need any change in the code that access this data.
This can be also equated to server side encryption.

If you want custom encryption to be applied to the files in hdfs, it will be little complex, because you have to apply the encryption/decryption logic in all the programs that uses these data. If the data is encrypted using custom encryption logic, the RecordReader and RecordWriter classes needs to be modified to work with the data.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer .....i am trying to encrpyt it manually but cant work on the code ....may i get any help on this may i get any kind of code for the practical explaination